object has no attribute id when execute external API
It appears that I'm encountering an issue while transferring data from Odoo 16 to Odoo 17. Specifically, when I use the search_read method to retrieve data from all fields like this res = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, the_class, 'search_read', [domain], {'limit': 1})​, I encounter an error stating "unknown object has no attribute id." However, when I specify the fields I want to retrieve, such as the name like this res = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, the_class, 'search_read', [domain], {'fields': ['name'], 'limit': 1})​, the operation executes successfully.
this is the error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo17/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1765, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "/opt/odoo17/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 133, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "/opt/odoo17/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1792, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "/opt/odoo17/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1996, in dispatch
    result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "/opt/odoo17/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 222, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
  File "/opt/odoo17/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 722, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "/opt/odoo17/odoo/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 28, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo17/odoo/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 20, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo17/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 468, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo17/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 453, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo17/addons/Geofarm/migration/models/models.py", line 99, in migrate_step1
    farm_vals = self.search_record(models,uid,'ferme.gaia',[])
  File "/opt/odoo17/addons/Geofarm/migration/models/models.py", line 33, in search_record
    res = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, the_class, 'search_read', [domain], {'limit': 1})
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1122, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1464, in __request
    response = self.__transport.request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1166, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1182, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(resp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1354, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xmlrpc/client.py", line 668, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault 1: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/controllers/rpc.py", line 150, in xmlrpc_2\n    response = self._xmlrpc(service)\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons/base/controllers/rpc.py", line 130, in _xmlrpc\n    result = dispatch_rpc(service, method, params)\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 366, in dispatch_rpc\n    return dispatch(method, params)\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 37, in dispatch\n    res = execute_kw(db, uid, *params[3:])\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 59, in execute_kw\n    return execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 65, in execute\n    res = execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 50, in execute_cr\n    result = retrying(partial(odoo.api.call_kw, recs, method, args, kw), env)\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 133, in retrying\n    result = func()\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 462, in call_kw\n    result = _call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 435, in _call_kw_model\n    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 5021, in search_read\n    result = records.read(fields, **read_kwargs)\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 2989, in read\n    return self._read_format(fnames=fields, load=load)\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 3168, in _read_format\n    vals[name] = convert(record[name], record, use_name_get)\n  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/fields.py", line 3011, in convert_to_read\n    return value.id\nAttributeError: \'_unknown\' object has no attribute \'id\'\n'>

The above server error caused the following client error:
RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server Error
    RPCError@http://192.168.171.128:8017/web/assets/a644c0c/web.assets_web_dark.min.js:2873:319
    makeErrorFromResponse@http://192.168.171.128:8017/web/assets/a644c0c/web.assets_web_dark.min.js:2876:163
    jsonrpc/promise</<@http://192.168.171.128:8017/web/assets/a644c0c/web.assets_web_dark.min.js:2880:34


You can keep the list of fields empty if you wish to retrieve data from every field, but you must specify the "fields": []
Try the example below; it should resolve your problem.
res = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, the_class, 'search_read', [domain], {'fields': [], 'limit': 1})

Please refer to https://www.odoo.com/documentation/17.0/developer/reference/external_api.html for additional information.

yes i've tried that, but in fact in specific models, it's still have same error

Would you kindly let me know which model you are having trouble with? Please be aware that if the module containing the model is not installed, an error will occur.

the error is my custom model, let say the name is custom.farm

Have you tried using admin credentials? It is possible that the user you are attempting to access the model is blocked.

The error happens when Odoo tries to get the id of a many2one record in the convert_to_read function, it expects a record but finds _unknown.
Odoo sets the related model name to _unknown when it is not loaded.
Try to check your imports and the model names
